# How to get useful error messages in mysql query in php?

Tags: php

### HTML code

```
<form class="col s6 " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="last_name" type="text" name="name" class="validate">
      <label for="last_name">Certificate Name</label>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:20px;">ADD</button>
</form>
```

### PHP code

```
<?php
 include('footer.php'); 

include('conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["name"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `isodetail`(`title`) VALUES ('$name')";

    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($run)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Certi Added Successfully')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('isocerti.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Something Error!..please try Again..')</script>";
    }
}

 ?>
```

This shows an alert message saying `Something Error!..please try Again..`
so is it `mysqli_query` that has a mistake?

Comment: Use the `mysqli_error` function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
Example: `echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: it doesnt show any errors

Comment: @Sandra read about [variable parsing in strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). That code is correct as it is now.

Comment: Related: [how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the else-block you can see, how you can catch up MySQL-errors and display them in an alert.

```php
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["name"]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO isodetail(title) VALUES ('{$name}')";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($run) {
        echo "<script>alert('Certi Added Successfully');window.open('isocerti.php','_self');</script>";
    } else {
        $error = addslashes(mysqli_error($conn));
        echo "<script>alert('An Error occur: {$error}');</script>";
    }
}
```

References:
MySQLi-Error: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
Escape special characters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php <sub>(it does the job for this example)</sub>

Comment: @ArchiPatel So you have your correct error, now you can start debug it.
My first idea will be: `INSERT isodetail(title, name) VALUES ('{$name}', '')` but that's just a guess without knowledge about your database structure.

Comment: yes i got this ...Thank you so much.